# jQuery draggable - snap to browser?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using the following code to drag a div on my site:

```
    js13('#wrapper').live('mouseover', function () {
        js13(this).draggable();
    });
```

But i want to somehow snap it to the browser, so that it is not possible to drag it outside of the browser window bounds.

Is this possible somehow? ;)

Comment: Don't use `live`. It's deprecated. Use `on`.

Comment: jqueryui not jquery see [Containment](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement)
+1 live is deprecated with jquery 1.9

Comment: A feedback to our answers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iyesuz/1/edit)**</kbd>

I don't understand why you use draggable inside the `'mouseover'` function, and also the deprecated `live` method. Anyway:
**For that purpose use the `containment` property:**

E.g: if `#wrapper`'s parent is `body`, you can simply use:

```
$( "#wrapper" ).draggable({ containment: 'parent' });
```

Or like:

```
$( "#wrapper" ).draggable({ containment: $('SomeparentElement') });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the containment property (see the [draggable-api](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment))

In your case, you might try:

```
js13('#wrapper').live('mouseover', function () {
    js13(this).draggable( "option", "containment", $(window));
});
```

Not sure if this is a working solution, not tested.